# Internal server error after upload on s3 bucket from aws lambda

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I created aws lambda function based on laravel framework using bref. Link: https://bref.sh

I want to make friends aws S3 and aws lambda. 
This is my code:

```
//here I upload file to s3

Storage::disk('s3')->put('images/originals', $request->file('name'));
```

```
//My configuration

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXX+XXXXXXXX
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=my-bucket
```

When I upload file locally all work perfectly, but when I try to upload on s3 in lambda function
I got error:

> `{ "message" : "Internal server error" }`

I use this package for uploading to aws:

```
league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0
```

This is my serverless.yaml

```
service: demo

provider:
  name: aws
  region: us-east-1
  runtime: provided
  environment:
    # Laravel environment variables
    APP_STORAGE: '/tmp'
    iamRoleStatements:
    # Allow to put a file in the `my-bucket` S3 bucket
    - Effect: Allow
      Action: s3:PutObject
      Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*'

plugins:
  - ./vendor/bref/bref

functions:
  website:
    handler: public/index.php
    timeout: 28 # in seconds (API Gateway has a timeout of 29 seconds)
    layers:
      - ${bref:layer.php-73-fpm}
    events:
      -   http: 'ANY /test/'
      -   http: 'ANY /test/{proxy+}'
  artisan:
    handler: artisan
    timeout: 120 # in seconds
    layers:
      - ${bref:layer.php-73} # PHP
      - ${bref:layer.console} # The "console" layer
```

Maybe I have problem with permissions. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Response from amazon x-ray

[image: response of query]

Thank you

Comment: Can you post some more code

Comment: I added more information

Comment: A stacktrace of the error would be nice

Comment: Any reason for not using aws-sdk for PHP

Comment: I added response